# seven-digit number + 1-2 letters (if given) to take out in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, words

I don`t know if it is possible.
I wanted only the seven-digit number + 1-2 letters (if given) to take out.
e.g.:

```
1300165A panadol 5mg
panadol 1% *1370100
panadol 2 mg, CL: 1300232
1330186AA
```

Would like to get:

```
1300165A
1370100
1300232
1330186AA
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is your example in one field?  or are there separate fields and you want to extract one string per field?

Answer (score 2):

```
regexp_substr(your_string, '(^|\W)(\d{7}[A-Z]{0,2})(\W|$)', 1, 1, '', 2)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/617f9/1)

Comment: hi Egor, its given error :(
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @user2307664 - Did you replace `your_string` with your real column name?

Comment: Yes, i have replace it. 

select  regexp_substr(wt.post_txt, '(^|\W)(\d{7}[A-Z]{0,2})(\W|$)', 1, 1, '', 2)
from    wtrans wt
where   wt.POST_COUNT='0014095444'

Is it working with oralce 9i?

Comment: @user2307664 - Unfortunately, regexp operations are not available in Oracle 9  :-(